# How to run a for loop for promises in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, ecmascript-6, promise

I have a function that returns a promise. The promise actually reads a JSON file and pushes some data of that file in an array and returns that array. I am able to do it with a single file but I want to run a for loop with multiple file paths and want all the results (resolve) of each promise to be pushed into an array. What's the correct way of doing it?

In the following code directoryName is a result of a promise. This is basically an array of directory names. In the secondMethod function I am using just the first directory name from the array to operate on a file inside that directory. Assume each directory in the array will have the t.json file.

```
let secondMethod = function(directoryName) {
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let tJsonPath = path.join(directoryPath, directoryName[0], 't.json')
        jsonfile.readFile(tJsonPath, function(err, obj) {
            let infoRow = []
            infoRow.push(obj.name, obj.description, obj.license);
            resolve(infoRow)
        })
    }
    );
    return promise;
}
```

How can I run a loop on the directoryName array so that jsonfile.readFile is executed for each element of the array and the result of it can be stored in a global array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all` to map each name to a `Promise`. Also make sure to check and `reject` in case there's an error:

```
const secondMethod = function(directoryName) {
  return Promise.all(
    directoryName.map((oneName) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const tJsonPath = path.join(directoryPath, oneName, 't.json')
      jsonfile.readFile(tJsonPath, function(err, obj) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        const { name, description, license } = obj;
        resolve({ name, description, license });
      })
    }))
  );
};

// Invoke with:
secondMethod(arrOfNames)
  .then((results) => {
    /* results will be in the form of
    [
      { name: ..., description: ..., license: ... },
      { name: ..., description: ..., license: ... },
      ...
    ]
    */
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle errors
  });
```